# .htaccess 301 redirect - rename subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've changed a subdirectory name on my site from :

http://root.com/wordpress/...

to

http://root.com/resources/...

Unfortunately google still has all the /wordpress/ URLs indexed, so I need to 301 redirect all /wordpress/ pages to /resources/. How would I write this rule in the .htaccess file? And/or is there a better way to achieve this?

I've tried this rule, but it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
RewriteRule ^wordpress/(.*) http://www.root.com/resources/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`RedirectPermanent`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectpermanent) (part of `mod_alias`, not `mod_rewrite`)

```
RedirectPermanent /wordpress /resources
```

(Tested and working)

Comment: Nice solution, much better than stuffing around with regex.